# Spring Cloud Contract, "strict" mode?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I'm new to Cloud Contract, I integrated it in a Producer microservice and in its client, the Consumer microservice. I noticed that, if I add attributes to the REST entity on the Producer side, forgetting to update the groovy contract accordingly, I have no warning at all.

I can't find a good way to detect such a situation: I would like to have an error executing my IT tests when the contract doesn't "cover" some new attributes.

How could I achieve this result? Is there a configuration option somewhere to enable a "strict" mode, when generating the Producer tests?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell Spring Cloud Contract that the production code has changed

Comment: Thank you; any idea about how to achieve a similar result? Cloud contract should warn me if the returned JSON has fields not covered by assertions... can I achieve this in the base abstract class? I think there is no way...